# Mod_rewrite to specific basic auth user subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For a dev environment My DocumentRoot in apache points to /var/www. This folder contains the following structure:

```
/var/www/username1/projectname/
/var/www/username2/projectname/
/var/www/username3/projectname/
```

Using .htaccess/.htpasswd someone needs to login using basic auth. When the user logs in he/she will be moved to `/var/www/[hisorherusername]/[projectname]/`. Using this technique every developer should be pointed to his/her own code while still using the same subdomain.

For example, when username1 visits projectname.dev.mycompany.com. This user will then be shown the code to /var/www/username1/projectname/.

I want to prevent using dynamic virtual hosts by using a different subdomain for every user. This usually messes up stuff when using CMS's.

I got a long way but gets stuck in using the rewrite rules. This is what I currently have:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "The DEV"
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^([^\.]+).dev.company.com$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /%{REMOTE_USER}/%1/html/$1
```

This results in an endless stream of internal redirects. When I change the last rewrite rule to `^$` instead of ^(.+)$ it works fine for the root URL, but not for all other URL's. These will be rewritten to /var/www/$1 instead. I tried adding a condition to check if we are not already in /%{REMOTE_USER} but that doesn't seem to solve anything.

I see what is happening, but I don't see a solution. I like to prevent adding another .htaccess rule in the subdirectories, since this should then be merged together with the .htaccess files of the projects themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally found it myself. This might help out people in the future. The first step is to create a virtual host to /var/www/. There you store the following .htaccess file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Typify DEV"
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/users/(.+)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^([^\.]+).dev.company.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /users/%{REMOTE_USER}/%1/html/$1
```

Unfortunately you cannot use %{REMOTE_USER} in your rewrite condition comparison. You may only use regular expressions on the right side. So I moved all user directories to a 'users' subdirectory:

```
/var/www/users/username1/project1
```

Now I can recognize if it already has been rewritten to that subdirectory. Quite easy solution actually.

Answer (score 1):

*Maybe this will be helpful for someone in the future, who needs a similar mod_rewrite condition.*

It's true that you cannot use `%{REMOTE_USER}` in the rewrite conditions CondPattern but you can use both `%{REMOTE_USER}` and `%{REQUEST_URI}` in an concatenated TestString and a regex capturing group inside the CondPattern.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER}%{REQUEST_URI} !^([^/]+/)\1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+).dev.company.com$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /%{REMOTE_USER}/%1/html/$1
```